# App review: should I include "sms" as required device Capability because it does sms verification?

Tags: ios, sms

We are developing iOS app. In our app, user accounts are connected to phone numbers and our app does sms verification when user start using our app (like snapchat). We only use user's phone number for that purpose. Now, we are going to submit our app for review, should I declare sms capability as required?

Users need to be able to receive very first sms by whatever means, but we don't want to restrict our target devices too much (e.g., iPod touch user can receive verification code using their Android and use our app on iPod touch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only add something to the "required device capability" list if your app can't function without it (or can't function with it).

If your app can workaround the device not having the capability then don't put it in the list. If your app doesn't function without the capability, then add it to the list.